# How to change user priority of submitting a job in cluster.(grid engine)

Tags: grid, system-administration

If there are multiple users in cluster and want to set high priority for one user(to submit his jobs first). How can i do this?

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: how do you submit your jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Normal user can't change job priority.

Only SGE admin can change that by following command

shell> qalter -p [priority valus] [job id]